# Eclipe kepler not showing svn path and version for the project

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

Not getting SVN version number and path here, even though this is checked out from SVN.

[image]

Comment: Also tried it in project explorer. Issue still exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at `Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations` and check you have `SVN` enabled.

Also look at `Preferences > Team > SVN > Label Decorations` to see which SVN decorations are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed the plugin and the problem got solved. thanks a lot.